# The order of residual field of $p$-adic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $L/ \Bbb{Q}_p$ be finite extension. Let $o$ be ring of integers of $L$.Let $π$ be a uniformizer, and $q$ be order of residue field.

I want to determine the order of $(o/\pi^no)^\times $.
I know the answer, which is $q^n-q^{n-1}$.

I guess this is just $\phi(q^n)$($Φ$ is Euler function),
but I don't know the reason why.

How can I prove  $＃(o/\pi^no)^\times＝q^n-q^{n-1}$?

Comment: The question is ill-defined. What is $n$ ? what is $\pi$ ? Are you sure you do not have extra assumptions on your extension ?

Comment: It is clear from context that $\pi$ is a uniformiser.

Comment: Your formula for $(o/\pi^n o)^\times$ is incorrect. Indeed, $o/\pi o$ is the residue field of $L$ and its order depends on the residual degree of the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I think in this case $q$ is meant to be the order of the residue field of $L$.

Comment: Doesn't this smell of induction? Is the case $n=1$ clear? Any thoughts how to relate the cases $n$ and $n+1$?

Comment: By the way, unless $q$ is a prime itself, $\phi(q^n) \neq q^n-q^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q$ be the cardinality of the residue field of $L$. Then, for example by Proposition 5.4.5 (vii) in Gouvea's excellent book, any element in $O/\pi^n O$ can be written as a sum
$$
a_0+a_1\pi+a_2\pi^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}\pi^{n-1},
$$
where $a_i\in O/\pi O$. Thus the order of $O/\pi^n O$ is $q^n$. Now suppose that a coset in $O/\pi^n O$ is a unit in $O/\pi^n O$. It is easy to see that any representative of this coset must have $a_0\neq 0$. Hence the non-units in $O/\pi^n O$ are precisely of the form
$$
a_1\pi+a_2\pi^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}\pi^{n-1}.
$$
In particular, there are $q^{n-1}$ of them.